# Get a specific number from a line and append it

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I am trying to filter a specific line of my file, **to only get the number from it**.

My file is locate in, /home/evaluation/**studentName**, and contains this :

- English 18
- History 18
- Math 18
- Total : 90/100

But could also contains this :

- Enlgish 14
- History 14
- Total : 70/100

So each student has its own marks.

---

I'd like to filter the **total** number only.
So it will show : **90** or **70**.

And then simply append that number inside of the student file.

---

**So far I went to this** :

```
for file in /home/evaluation/* ; do
    awk -v tot="$tot" '{sum+=$2} END {print "Total", (sum/(tot*20))*100"/100"}' "$file" >> "$file"
result=$(grep "Total" "$file" | cut d' ' -f2)
echo "$result" >> $file
done
```

But it doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like below ?

```
for file in /home/evaluation/*  
 do 
  result=$(cat $file | grep Total | cut -d':' -f2 | cut -d'/' -f1) 
  echo "$result" >> $file
 done
```

Comment: Avoid useless `cat`: `result=$(grep Total <$file | ...`!

Answer (score 1):

## One line `sed` solution:

There is a simple command for all the job

Presuming `Total` is already the last line:

```
sed 's/Total \([0-9]\+\)\/[0-9]\+ *$/&\n\1/' -i /home/evaluation/*
```

And if Total isn't the last line, things become a litle more complex:

```
sed '/Total/{ h; s/Total \+\([0-9]\+\)\/.*$/\1/; x; };$G' -i /home/evaluation/*
```

Comment: Care about `-i` flag!  You could use `-i.bak` to create backups files...